# Who in the universe am I?

Tags: riddle

I love it green, but I inherited a blue one from my father, who now fancies red instead.

My father did not have a father himself, and my sister loves to do solo.

Who am I?

Comment: nice one! made me regret peeking at the answer

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I am

> Luke Skywalker.

I like green

> Yoda

I inherited a blue

> Lightsaber

from my father

> Anakin (who is fatherless)

who prefers a red one since

> he became Darth Vader.

My sister is

> Leia

who likes to do

> Han Solo.

Comment: Lovely answer. I think it's correct. @IanF1

Comment: It fits, I would be surprised if you are wrong.  gj

Comment: Correct. I like green should intentionally be referring to the color of the lightsaber Luke made for himself.